# How to configure SQL Server transactional web synchronization/replication?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, iis, replication

I have to configure a (transactional) replication where it will have one distributor(publisher too) and more 6 servers that will be the subscribers.

The problem is: I never configured something like that, and after a whole week looking for a tutorial for do this, I decided to ask here because it's a task harder than I've imagined.
I already tried the MSDN tutorials, but without success. I know how to create a publication and subscribe it, but I don't know how to synchronize it with IIS(Internet Information Service).
The intention is: Sync it with IIS to the subscribers update the databases via web.
Note: I already tried ALL the MSDN tutorials. None of them worked.
So, I'm asking for any other way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

(I'm using Sql Server 2005 on Windows Server 2003) :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like web synchronization in SQL Server is available only for merge replication, not transactional too.
From MSDN:

> Use the Web Synchronization Wizard to configure a Microsoft Internet
>   Information Services (IIS) server for Web synchronization, which
>   allows you to synchronize subscriptions to merge publications over an
>   Internet or intranet connection. For more information, see [Web
>   Synchronization for Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [How to: Configure IIS
>   for Web Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152511%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

**Much later edit, after reading comments.**

Web synchronization supports indeed only merge replication.

In cases when the changes at the subscriber shouldn't propagate back to the publisher (design decision, whatever), the merge replication can be configured to mark published articles as read-only. Meaning that changes are not pushed back, similarly to transactional replication.

More to the point, merge replication supports a feature called Read-Only Articles (tables, etc), described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151733.aspx). 
It says that:

> Specify whether changes at the Subscriber are uploaded to the
>   Publisher. For applications in which some or all data should be
>   read-only at the Subscriber, download-only articles provide a
>   performance benefit.

Comment: I guess it's just about the Web Synchronization Wizard, but I'm doing it manually.

Comment: In understand, but I think that if they had support for it then it would be available in the wizard. Additionally, I haven't been able to find any reference to "transactional web replication" anywhere on MSDN.

Comment: so you are saying that it's not possible to make a transactional sql replication using IIS?

Comment: I'm pretty sure about this. Really couldn't find anything. And a feature like this should be at least briefly documented somewhere on MSDN, next to the merge web sync. Can I ask why can't you use merge sync? It's the same, especially if at the subscriber the db is read-only.

Comment: My intention is: Send data from one central server to 6 other affiliates servers, just send. As far as I know, the Merge Replication send and receive data. Is there a way to just send without receiving?

Comment: Yes, even with Merge Replication. Just don't modify the subscription database. Then there's nothing to send back.

Comment: Ok, but the subscription database must be in modification too. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: OK, there is. Merge replication supports a feature called Read-Only Articles (tables, etc). Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151733.aspx. It says that: **Specify whether changes at the Subscriber are uploaded to the Publisher. For applications in which some or all data should be read-only at the Subscriber, download-only articles provide a performance benefit.*